# Save a variable into controller

Tags: symfony

I have this form first:

```
            <form action="{{path('entrenamiento_new')}}" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
            <fieldset>
              <legend> Seleccione </legend>
              <p><label> <input type="radio" name="tipoentrenamiento_id" value="1" checked="true"> Tipo X7 </label></p>
              <p><label> <input type="radio" name="tipoentrenamiento_id" value="0"> Otro</label></p>
             </fieldset>

            <p><input type="submit" value="Continuar &rarr;"></p>
        </form>
```

And this is the routing:

```
entrenamiento_new:
pattern: entrenamiento/new
defaults: {_controller: GitekUdaBundle:Entrenamiento:new}
requirements:
    _method: POST
    id: \d+
```

Now I have a post variable tipoentrenamiento_id witch I want to save into Formacion entity when I process the formacion/new controller.

How can I save this data in the createAction?? My Formacion entity has a tipoentrenamiento_id field already.

Comment: what is "Formacion" and what is your question actually anyway? your post is to confusing and not to the point. variables you provide to templates as a parameter to the render()-method and POST variables you get through the Request-object.

Comment: Formacion is my entity and I want to save the post variable tipoentrenamiento_id into this entity manually

Comment: I don't see any entity in your post ... all I see is a form, a route ... you don't mention your favorite animal BTW :) what keeps you from doing what you want to do? god? bullies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need to store a Post value in the controller you can use

$entity->setXxxxxx('value) for that where Xxxxx is the name of your field in the Entity.

For example, assuming your entity field name is "tipoentenamiento_id", your controller must be:

```
public function newAction()
{
    $request = $this->getRequest();

//Get your POST value
    $foo = $request->request->get('tipoentrenamiento_id');

    $entrenamiento = new Entrenamiento();
    $entrenamiento->setTipoentrenamientoId($foo);
    $form   = $this->createForm(new EntrenamientoType(), $entrenamiento);

    return array(
        'entrenamiento' => $entrenamiento,
        'form'   => $form->createView()         

    );
}
```